# Get paragraphs formatting by numbering

Tags: c#, macros, powerpoint-2010

PowerPoint has 2 types of paragraphs formatting: Bullets and Numbering.
Getting Bullets is peaty easy: `ParagraphFormat.Bullet` and from this object we can take style,type,character, etc... But what about Numbering? 
If I have 2 paragraphs: 
`1.1 par1
1.2 par2`

ParagraphFormat.Bullet object doesn't returns correct values.
How I can

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to get Numbering of paragraphs?

Comment: Yes, but index doesn't ok for this case. For example we have next paragraphs: 
1. Par1
2. Par2
I need to know how numbering looks like "1." or "1)", etc...